# What is the irreducible head of a principal indecomposable $R$-module $M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

What is the irreducible head of a principal indecomposable $R$-module $M$?

and some properties of the irreducible head of $R$-module $M$?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Where are you encountering this?

Comment: Some articles concerning the Cellular Algebra.

Answer (score 2):

The **head** (or **top**) of a module is defined to be $M/J(M)$ where $J(M)$ denotes the Jacobson radical of the module.

When $R$ is a perfect ring, then the head/top of every principal indecomposable module is a simple module (which is what I think you mean by irreducible module). Not sure what other properties you are interested in. Obviously it can't be projective unless $J(M)=\{0\}$, since $M$ is a projective cover for its head.

Did you read [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_indecomposable_module) that outlines all of this?

Comment: Thank you!  I have read the definition of it in wiki, but not absolutely sure some properties of it.